# FAIconLibrary addIcon method started throwing error

Tags: angular, font-awesome-5

I have created an FAIcon Module and i am using FaiconLibrary.addIcons() method to include few icons. This was working perfectly fine but just now, i got fresh copy and did npm install and started getting following error. I tried removing node_modules and did clean cache as well, did't work.

```
 error TS2345: Argument of type 'import("/node_modules/@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons/node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-common-types/index").IconDefinition' is not assignable to parameter of type 'import("/node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-common-types/index").IconDefinition'.
  Types of property 'iconName' are incompatible.
    Type 'import("/node_modules/@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons/node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-common-types/index").IconName' is not assignable to type 'import("/node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-common-types/index").IconName'.
      Type '"acquisitions-incorporated"' is not assignable to type 'IconName'.

24        library.addIcons(faEye);
```

This is how it is implemented.

[image]
~~~~~

Following are the dependencies i am using

```
 "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^12.2.16",
    "@angular/cdk": "^12.2.13",
    "@angular/common": "^12.2.16",
    "@angular/compiler": "^12.2.16",
    "@angular/core": "^12.2.16",
    "@angular/forms": "^12.2.16",
    "@angular/material": "^12.2.9",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^12.2.16",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^12.2.16",
    "@angular/router": "^12.2.16",
    "@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome": "^0.9.0",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.3.0",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.15.4",
    "@nrwl/angular": "12.10.0",
    "@storybook/addon-a11y": "^6.3.12",
    "@storybook/addon-storysource": "^6.3.12",
    "material-design-icons": "^3.0.1",
    "ncp": "^2.0.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "~12.3.0",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template": "~12.3.0",
    "@angular-eslint/template-parser": "~12.3.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^12.2.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^12.2.0",
    "@nrwl/cli": "12.10.0",
    "@nrwl/cypress": "12.10.0",
    "@nrwl/eslint-plugin-nx": "12.10.0",
    "@nrwl/jest": "12.10.0",
    "@nrwl/linter": "12.10.0",
    "@nrwl/storybook": "12.10.0",
    "@nrwl/tao": "12.10.0",
    "@nrwl/workspace": "12.10.0",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials": "~6.3.0",
    "@storybook/angular": "~6.3.0",
    "@storybook/builder-webpack5": "~6.3.0",
    "@storybook/manager-webpack5": "~6.3.0",
    "@types/jest": "27.0.2",
    "@types/node": "14.14.33",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "~4.31.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "~4.31.1",
    "cypress": "^8.3.0",
    "eslint": "7.22.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "8.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-cypress": "^2.10.3",
    "jest": "27.2.3",
    "jest-preset-angular": "10.0.1",
    "ng-packagr": "^12.1.1",
    "prettier": "^2.3.1",
    "ts-jest": "27.0.5",
    "typescript": "~4.3.5"
  }
```

tried without using library.AddIcon and got same error

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a version mismatch issue
https://github.com/FortAwesome/angular-fontawesome/issues/125

Comment: Thank you for taking time and sending me that link, i have been searching since yesterday and couldn't solve this issue, but the resolution mentioned into that link worked, i just had to correct the version in package-lock.json file. Surprisingly this issues was raised several years back, but i faced it just yesterday, previously my project was working perfectly fine.

Comment: I ran into the same issue, what version did u change in package-lock.json? I have both 0.3.0 and ˆ0.2.36.. where u handling similar versions? I can't find what kind of change should I apply

Comment: updated to fontawesome 6.. solved